# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-core@5.8.38

Tags: npm, babeljs, npm-install

I was trying to install babel and babel presets. But I seem to encountered a critical error that prevents me from installation.

I typed in the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-react
```

but it rejects me with the following error message:

```
    └─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-core@5.8.38
  └─┬ regenerator@0.8.40
    ├─┬ defs@1.1.1
    │ └── esprima-fb@15001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb 
    ├── esprima-fb@15001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb 
    └─┬ recast@0.10.33
      └── esprima-fb@15001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /babel/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.9
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.9
npm WARN babel-loader@6.2.4 requires a peer of babel-core@^6.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN graphql_demo@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN graphql_demo@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Could this be caused by [the left-pad fiasco](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141577284765/kik-left-pad-and-npm)? Babel seems to depend on it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The left-pad package has been restored, and if I recall correctly, Babel have already pushed a release that no longer relies on it. Either way, it shouldn't be the issue here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I additionally had to add a dependency for `jspm` in order for the babel-loader to be correctly installed.

```
…
"dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "jspm": "^0.16.48",
    …
}
```